# Redactor - Move back from li element to p element not possible

Tags: wysiwyg, redactor, statamic

I use redactor for a textfield.
When I add a list inside the redactor field and underneath I want to commence with a normal paragraph text then its not possible to leave a bullet list.
Not with clicking 'enter' two times.
Not with clicking the li button and not even with highlighting the last li element and choose paragraph text in the toolbar.

There is just no way to move back to paragraph text. The same is with block quotes.

Does anyone experience a similar behavior?

Comment: What is the version number that you used to Redactor?

Comment: Try to update Redactor :)

Comment: Yeah thanks for the great tip. Unfortunately redactor comes within a cms and is not update trough me because I had to buy a 200$ licence. No thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to update Redactor because the last `change-log` fix your problem : http://imperavi.com/redactor/log/